# Protobuf: Maximum memory size for the Arena

Tags: c++, memory, protocol-buffers, allocation, pool

I am evaluating Protobuf Arena allocation to use with non protobuf related classes. Just as a tool to easily allocate/deallocate objects from a memory pool.

I haven't found in its API (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.arena#Arena) a way to specify the maximum memory for the arena to use. I want to cap the memory usage and allow the program using the Arena to die rather than consume more memory than expected.

Is there any other C++ library for memory pool management that's worth to check? The Protobuf arena is quite easy to use, that's why I started with it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no real built-in functionality for capping the memory usage, but I believe you could achieve the same result by setting the right hooks on the [ArenaOptions](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.arena#ArenaOptions). You would want to set the `on_arena_init` and `on_arena_allocation` hooks in particular. In `on_arena_init` you can create an object to store your state (probably just a counter of bytes allocated so far) and return that as a `void*`. Then each time the Arena needs to allocate more memory, it will call your `on_arena_allocation` hook and pass in your `void*` as the `cookie` argument, so you can update your size counter and assert that it is below your designated memory cap. Note that this will track the blocks of memory fetched by the Arena from the system allocator, not blocks of memory handed out by the Arena to the application code, but it sounds like this is probably the behavior you want. You might also need to set the `on_arena_reset` and `on_arena_destruction` hooks: the former to reset your counter to zero and the latter to delete your cookie to avoid a memory leak.